# MySQL using max(date) in a between statement

Tags: mysql, max, case, between

Any help is appreciated.  I am trying to use max(date) in a CASE statement and I can't get the syntax right or ??

```
// This works    
SELECT
     ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN Document_Date BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") AND  DATE_FORMAT("2019-01-31", "%Y-%m-%d") THEN GTotal END),0) TOTAL2019
FROM
salesdata

// But I want to use max(Document_Date) which is 2019-01-31 like so and have tried cast and different combos, but it comes out null or says invalid use of group function.  Document_Date is datetime in DB

    SELECT
         ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN Document_Date BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") AND  DATE_FORMAT(max(Document_Date), "%Y-%m-%d") THEN GTotal END),0) TOTAL2019
    FROM
    salesdata
```

What am I doing wrong - thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to use `max` aggregate withing `sum`. Generally you cannot do this without using subqueries.

Check my alternative solution

```
SELECT
     ROUND(sum(
       CASE WHEN Document_Date BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") AND  (select max(Document_date) from salesData) THEN 
         GTotal 
       END),
     0) TOTAL2019
FROM
salesdata
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly!  Really appreciate it!  Also, for anyone else using this code there is one parenthesis missing right before select subquery.  DATE_FORMAT((select...

Comment: If this answer is useful for you, please consider to mark it as answer so the community can also benefit from it

Comment: Note that `DATE_FORMAT("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")` doesn't actually do anything